# QGIS 3x - categorized style customization based on a part of the string

Tags: qgis, symbology, digitizing

I have a problem.
I am digitizing the map and I want to distinguish one group of polygons from the other group.
The basic difference between them lies in their ID (string). One of them has the ID starting from SE-1-... and the other ones start from SE-2-...

I found some hints here:

[How to select features containing specific text string using an expression in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153613/how-to-select-features-containing-specific-text-string-using-an-expression-in-qg/153617)

which unfortunately doesn't work in my example.
Once I write down the function, next press the "Add" (plus) button I am getting the box allocated for "All other values".
[image]

Is there any way to separate these 2 groups by this part of the string?
Categorizing by ID doesn't make sense, because all polygon get their unique color, which makes a terrible mess.

UPDATE:

Function is not valid, the details are in the box below:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Cyrmel:
The formula is `"TITLE" LIKE '%SE-2%'` and than you have to classify (to 1/0 or true/false). If you want, you can also change manually the 0 and 1 in the legend.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You did not specify the value which triggers whether your polygon should go into the first group or not - `"TITLE" LIKE %SE-2%` returns 1 for true and 0 for false. instead of "all other Values", set one colour to 1 and one to 0.

Comment: So what formula you suggest?

Answer (score 3):

### Assuming Consistent Formatting in `TITLE` Field

The expression `substr("TITLE", 4, 1)` returns the fourth character of the string. If the `TITLE` field is consistently formatted, this will correspond to the particular category, either 1 or 2. Just enter that expression and click **classify**.

[image: categorize on substring]

Alternatively, you could modify `substr`'s starting position and length, or if the SE-# is always at the beginning, simply use `left("TITLE", 4)` to get the SE-# text, not just the number.

[image: categorize on longer substring]

### Inconsistent Formatting in `TITLE` Field

If the SE-# text does not consistently appear at the beginning of the string, you can use the `regex_substr` function. This is easiest for grabbing the entire SE-# text, but can be modified to grab just the number, or you can nest it within a `right` function instead.

`regexp_substr("TITLE", 'SE-[1,2]')`

[image: regex substring]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Conditional expressions like IF or CASE?
Something like  if(  "TITLE"  =  'SE-1' , 1, 0 )